# Nurse scheduling example: preventing overlapping shifts

Tags: python, scheduling, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am still a beginner with constraint programming and I am currently trying to implement a nurse scheduling problem in Python which is similar to the example provided on [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling#nurse_scheduling).

However, in my scheduling problem, there are multiple patients that each have the same number of shifts on each day but at different time points during the day. The constraint I am trying to implement should ensure that a given nurse is not assigned to shifts that overlap each other in time. For example, if patient X has a shift from 10-12 AM and patient Y a shift from 9-11 AM, a given nurse should only be assigned to one of these shifts. How would one go about implementing this?

My approach was to create two separate lists (or a tuple list combining them):

(1) One to define the duration of each shift, `shift_duration` (a list of elements each representing the duration of a shift in hours)

(2) One to define the shifts starting time, `shift_starting_point` (a list of elements ranging from 0 to 24 each representing a shift) in another list (typewise similar to `shift_requests` in the example).

I was trying to apply the `AddNoOverlap` method from the [Job Shop Problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop), but I could not figure out how to combine them into a hard constraint rule using this method. I also don't know whether that approach makes a lot of sense. I'd appreciate any help - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the easy approach:

```
for each conflicting pair of shifts (a, b):
  for each nurse n:
    model.AddBoolOr([assign_a_n.Not(), assign_b_n.Not()])
```

I know this is quadratic, but it is simple.

Comment: I guess I could also just take the sum in a list of shifts that overlap like so:  `model.Add(sum(overlapping_shifts) <= 1)`

Comment: Yes, but the solver will build the clique itself.